# jQuery mobile show and hide don't seem to work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, show-hide

I'm trying to use jQuery show and hide which seem to work ok in Safari, when I try it on the iPhone, it doesn't work at all. Here is my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#showSearch").click(function () {
  $("#searchform").show(1000);

});
</script>
```

It's a button that when clicked, will show the search form. The form doesn't show on iPhone. Also when I add `$('#showSearch').remove();` in there, it doesn't get removed, even if I add a function as the second parameter of `show()` it still doesn't hide the button.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery Docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/show/  (Shows)
- http://api.jquery.com/hide/  (Hides)
- http://api.jquery.com/remove/  (Deletes)
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/  (Show/Hide)

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/qQnsj/1/

JS

```
$('#viewMeButton').click(function() {
   $('#viewMe').toggle(); // used toggle instead of .show() or .hide()
});

$('#removeMeButton').click(function() {
   $('#removeMe').remove(); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="viewMe">
            Hello I'm in the div tag, can you see me?
        </div>
        <br />
        <button id="viewMeButton">Show / Hide</button>
        <br />
        <div id="removeMe">
            Click the button to remove me
        </div>
        <br />
        <button id="removeMeButton">Remove Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Ok so I figured out that I need to wrap `$('#pageid').live( 'pageinit',function(event){ }` around the function for it to be recognised by the particular page. But i'm still having the problem where `$("#showSearch").remove()` doesn't hide the showSearch button. In your example you've created a second div to remove the link, but I want the button I click to disappear once clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had a similar problem. Hopefully this will help someone else if they find this question, too.

I was trying to hide a set of ui-block-* elements in a JQM grid. On the same grid cells, my media query for the iPhone was setting display: block !important. That was winning.

The !important directive was unnecessary in my case and when I removed it the calls to hide() and show() began working as expected.